# Characters can't appear

Tags: html

I have this:

```
 <label for="label">Name of label</label>
 <input type="text" name="label" id="label" />
```

The Name of label is in other language and I take other character which is something like ΞΞ½ΞΏΞΌΞ±

How can I fix this problem and leave a specific space between the label and button?

Comment: Have you added metadata of encoding?

Comment: set char type in `<meta>` tag

Comment: Use CSS for formating specific things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add corresponding character set in head.

More information [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp)

For the specific space, try this.

```
 <label for="label">Name of label</label>
 <input type="text" name="label" id="label" style="margin-left:100px;"/>
```

change 100 with your own space